# Thread.join() and synchronization?

Tags: java, multithreading

Is Thread.join() a full synchronization with flushing of caches  etc. when performed of the thread beeing joined?

Answer (score 5):

I *think* you're asking whether from thread T1 that calls join on T2, code in T1 reading data after the `join()` will definitely see changes written by T2. If that's the case, then the answer is yes, due to [JLS 17.4.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.4):

> The final action in a thread T1 synchronizes-with any action in another thread T2 that detects that T1 has terminated.
>
> *T2 may accomplish this by calling T1.isAlive() or T1.join().*

and [JLS 17.4.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5):

> All actions in a thread *happen-before* any other thread successfully returns from a `join()` on that thread.

Answer (score 0):

The method thread.join [allows](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/join.html):

> one thread to wait for the completion of another. If t is a Thread object whose thread is currently executing,
>
> ```
> t.join();
> ```
>
> causes the current thread to pause execution until t's thread terminates.

This is not related to synchronization, but only to sequence of steps.

If you have **only two threads** and you wait the reader thread waits the end of writer thread with method join, this can be used as a mechanism of synchronization, but it is not.