# Does C# Thread.Join Guarantee Memory Coherence?

Tags: c#, multithreading

The first answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37839010/thread-join-and-synchronization) cites the Java Language Specification to the effect that Thread.Join and Thread.IsAlive, when called from thread T2 on thread T1, synchronizes-with T1 when T2 thereby detects that T1 has terminated.

I can't find anything comparable to the JLS that answers this question: Is the above also true for C#?

If so, does it guarantee memory coherence? That is, does it guarantee that all writes to memory by T1 will be visible to T2?

Comment: It can readily assume it is true.  You can't get the same warranty because it is [not in Microsoft's control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/hosting/ihosttask-interface).  Nobody actually does that.

Comment: I'm sorry, Hans. Your writing here is usually among the most helpful, but I'm confused this time. When you say, "nobody actually does that," what is "that?"

Comment: Nobody implements that interface.  Goes back to the days when everybody insisted that "green threads" were essential.  Then they got it in .NET 2.0, and discovered they weren't.  In fact were harmful after the multi-core revolution that happened at the same time.  The SQL Server team's decision to not use the interface was probably the most influential.  15 years ago, getting to be ancient history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From MSDN Magazine, back a few years - [The C# Memory Model in Theory and Practice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2012/december/csharp-the-csharp-memory-model-in-theory-and-practice) which was a two-parter.

What it has to say is this:

> All other threading APIs in the .NET Framework, such as Thread.Start and ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem, also make a similar guarantee. In fact, nearly every threading API must have some barrier semantics in order to function correctly. *These are almost never documented*, but can usually be deduced simply by thinking about what the guarantees would have to be in order for the API to be useful.

(My *emphasis*)

Of course, what we're actually seeking are details of *.NET*s memory model, not C#, since it's the runtime that'll offer any guarantees, but as suggested above, I cannot find any more concrete documentation.

Comment: Yeah, I found that too, before posting my question. The part you emphasized certainly raised my eyebrows when I read it. His article refers separately to the "Standard ECMA-334 C# Language Specification," which I have downloaded and read, and to "the Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5." I can't find anything that answers my question in ECMA-334, and he says .NET is the subject of the second part of the two-part article. I couldn't find the second part either. Do you know a link?

Comment: This is [part two](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/january/csharp-the-csharp-memory-model-in-theory-and-practice-part-2) but I'm not sure it'll get you further forward.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the link! Yeah, that doesn't do much more, and his wrap-up is what everyone always says: avoid low-level stuff and use locks, etc. I am following his advice, but I have a case where I know T1 will exit before T2 needs what T1 wrote. If Thread.IsAlive works in C#/.NET like the JLS says it does for Java, I don't need locks. I just want an authority like the JLS that I can put my faith in.

Comment: Marking this as the accepted answer, as it would appear this is as good an answer as there is. And thanks again for the link to Part 2.